# data.table SD which.max with a column name

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Probably very simple.

I'm trying to use `R` `data.table`'s `.SD` to retain the row with the maximum value by a certain column.

This is my `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[sample(26,100,replace=T)],value=rnorm(100),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

And this would be the `data.table` code:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(value)],by=id]
```

Which works fine.

Now suppose I don't know what the name of the value column is but rather am passed it as a parameter:
value.name <- "value"

So I thought this'd work:

```
dt <- setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(value.name)],by=id]
```

But it's throwing the warnings:

```
 In which.max(value.name) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

and returning an empty `data.table`.

Any idea?

Comment: Try `setorderv(setDT(df), value.name); unique(df, by="id", fromLast=TRUE)`. By the way, overwriting your df like `df <- f(df)` makes for an annoying example, since we have to go back to the top and recreate it to run subsequent parts. Also, if you're going to wrap in data.frame(), why are you even using data.table? Have you noticed the `setDF` function yet?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `get()`

```
dt <- setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(get(value.name))], by = id]
```